Badminton Racquet String tension and durability of racquet
I just bought Yonex nanoray light 18i Racquet, I just want to know what string tension I can get it strung so that the durablity of the racquet is not compormised. Kindly suggest.

I am a intermidiate player.
Need some power in racquet for smashing shuttle.
It has inbuilt 30 lbs capacity.

